# How to show random divs on page load?

Tags: jquery, html, random

I need to show 3 random divs on each page load.

```
<div class="job-block1">
<h1> job block 1's content </h1>
</div>

<div class="job-block2">
<h1> job block 2's content </h1>
</div>

<div class="job-block3">
<h1> job block 3's content </h1>
</div>

<div class="job-block4">
<h1> job block 4's content </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u show us what u tried, I because right now I don't really understand what u want. If u want to show on page load, u can use `$(function(){ ... })` and u put some logic for displaying divs.

Comment: What do you mean by "random divs?" is the content inside random? Is the class name random? Are you trying to generate these random divs programmatically on page load, changing each time?

Answer (score -1):

A way to do this is by having the `div`s hidden on page load and then showing a few randomly.

You can use `$(document).ready(function(){ /*function body*/ })`

And in the function body have a few randomizers using `Math.random()`

If you need more help, let me know and I'll try to post a full code snippet